# How to get the ImageView of captured image bitmap from a CameraController to fill the whole parent view?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-camerax

I've been stuck with a seemingly simple task: After taking a picture, display this picture in the full ViewPort of the CameraPreview.

Answers in related questions did not solve my problem (as I explain further below).

Trying to get a bitmap that I get from an ImageCapture's onCaptureSuccess listener to scale just does not work.
I have tried to do this with the "classic" setup using a CameraProvider and binding my Preview and ImageCapture use cases to this, before I changed my approach to use the AndroidX CameraController approach. With both cases, I made sure to have the same ViewPort for both use cases, tried to resize/crop the resulting image to have the same aspect ratio/resolution as the Preview, experimented with the `adjustViewBounds` property, no luck, the image will always be in the center of the Preview but scaled way down (I am aware that the resulting resolution is by default much higher than my screen's resolution, I don't mind to scale the image down or crop it, as long as it fills the whole screen):

[Screenshot of the photo not taking up the entire preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n49Xa.png)

Relevant portions of my code:

## Layout File

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragments.CameraFragment">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

     <!-- Buttons and other stuff -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## CameraFragment

Initalizations of preview use case and ImageView:

```
    private lateinit var imagePreview: ImageView
    private lateinit var viewFinder: PreviewView
    private lateinit var cameraController: LifecycleCameraController
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private lateinit var preview: Preview


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        cameraView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false)
cameraView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener)
        imagePreview = cameraView.findViewById(R.id.image_preview)
        imagePreview.isVisible = false

        val previewView: PreviewView = cameraView.findViewById(R.id.viewFinder)
        previewView.controller = cameraController

        ...

        return cameraView
    }
```

startCamera(), called in the fragment's onCreate():

```
    private fun startCamera() {
        cameraController = LifecycleCameraController(requireContext())
        cameraController.bindToLifecycle(this)
    }
```

takePicture() implementation for the cameraController object:

```
        cameraController.takePicture(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                    Log.d("ImageCapture", "Success")
                    val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
                    val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
                    buffer[bytes]
                    val bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)

                    imagePreview.rotation = image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat()
                    imagePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage)
                    imagePreview.isVisible = true
                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e("ImageCapture", "Failed to capture image: $exception")
                    super.onError(exception)
                }
            })
```

As explained before, I am not cropping the image anymore (because the way I understood the LifeCycleController, it does this for you) - even though I also tried cropping approaches with this before, without success.
The cropping approaches included: Cropping and resizing to the exact size of the device/viewport, using the croptrect object of the ImageProxy.
I am starting to think my problem is a simple ImageView <> Layout problem rather than the camera issue?

## Edit

Cropping the imageProxy like so does not help either:

```
val croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    bitmapImage, 
    image.cropRect.left, 
    image.cropRect.top, 
    image.cropRect.width(), 
    image.cropRect.height()
)
```

Comment: You will need the cropping. The ImageProxy is not cropped. It's "cropped" by providing a crop rect, comparing to no crop rect provided.

Comment: @Xi张熹 I tried cropping: `val croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapImage, image.cropRect.left, image.cropRect.top, image.cropRect.width(), image.cropRect.height())`. Same result.